# My scala case class function is not throwing an Exception error as expected

Tags: scala, generics, user-defined-functions

"Using a stringToInt function, write a function inside the companion
object of our Point case class that takes strings of x and y to create a new Point. A
default value of Zero(0) should be used if our stringToInt returns a None"

pls my function doesn't throw any Exception as shown below

```
case class Point(x: String, y: String)

object Point{

  def string2Int(sx: String, sy: String): Option[Int] = {

    try{
     Some(sx.toInt)
     Some(sy.toInt)
    }catch {
     case e: Exception => None
    }
  }
}
```

Point("100", "50")

Point("Jack","Bob")

pls, what can I add to the above code to make it return 0 as the default thrown 'Exception'instead of None?

Comment: I do not even understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: @simper. Welcome to SO. You could refer to this link to understand how to ask easy to understand questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Using a stringToInt function, write a function inside the companion object of our Point case class that takes strings of x and y to create a new Point. A default value of Zero(0) should be used if our stringToInt returns a None"

It does not say that you are supposed to throw exceptions.
In fact, that is very un-Scala-like.

They seem to want you to use Options and recover failures with default values instead.

---

How about this?

```
import scala.util.Try

case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)

object Point {

  val zero = Point(0,0)

  // Returns None if the String could not be parsed into an integer
  def stringToInt(x: String): Option[Int] = Try(x.toInt).toOption

  // apply is the traditional name for "constructor" functions
  // in a companion object
  // you can then do   
  //     val point = Point("10", "20")
  // in addition to the built-in 
  //     val point = Point(10, 20)
  def apply(x: String, y: String): Point = (
    for {
      px <- stringToInt(x) // use a for-comprehension over Options
      py <- stringToInt(y) // to only yield a value if both
    } yield Point(px, py)  // coordinates are valid ...
  ).getOrElse(zero)        // ... then getOrElse if they are not
}
```

Or alternatively, if you want to recover from the parsing errors individually:

```
  def apply(x: String, y: String): Point =
    Point(stringToInt(x).getOrElse(0),stringToInt(y).getOrElse(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Using a stringToInt function, write a function inside the companion
>   object of a Point case class that takes strings of x and y to create a
>   new Point. A default value of Zero(0) should be used if the
>   stringToInt returns a None". This was the question and I intend to
>   throw an Exception

If the `string2Int` returns `None`, you could set `Zero` or `throw new exception`

```
  case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)

  object Point{

    val Zero = Point(0,0)

    def string2Int(sx: String, sy: String): Option[Point] = {

      Try{
        Point(sx.toInt,sy.toInt)
      }.toOption
    }
  }

  val pt1 = Point.string2Int("100", "50")
  println(pt1.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException(s"Invalid input types")))

  // On invalid input, you could either send Zero or Raise exception

  println(Point.string2Int("John", "Bob").getOrElse(Point.Zero))
  println(Point.string2Int("John", "Bob").getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException(s"Invalid input types")))
```

NOTE: IMHO, instead of throwing exception from the function, you could let the caller of the function decide the next action point. We could just return `None` in the `.getOrElse` instead of throwing exception which will stop the program execution.

Comment: Not much point in returning `Option` if it can never return `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will prefer returning None. Waiting for the OP to clarify if he intends to throw an exception.

Comment: "Using a stringToInt function, write a function inside the companion
object of a Point case class that takes strings of x and y to create a new Point. A
default value of Zero(0) should be used if the stringToInt returns a None". This was the question and I intend to throw an Exception

Comment: @simper Thanks for the input. The above solution raises an Exception on invalid inputs. Please accept the answer if it helps.